# how to create dynamic multi level dropdown in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, html-select

i have dynamic json structure as mentioned below, need to fill tree like in the html drop down dynamically. there may be sub level, sub sub level, grand sub level ....

```
[{"Key":"001","Record":{"PrefcatID":"001","parentid":"0","prefname":"org1"}},{"Key":"002","Record":{"PrefcatID":"002","parentid":"0","prefname":"org2"}},{"Key":"003","Record":{"PrefcatID":"003","parentid":"0","prefname":"org3"}},{"Key":"004","Record":{"PrefcatID":"004","parentid":"001","prefname":"suborg1"}},{"Key":"005","Record":{"PrefcatID":"005","parentid":"001","prefname":"suborg2"}},{"Key":"006","Record":{"PrefcatID":"006","parentid":"002","prefname":"suborg1"}},{"Key":"007","Record":{"PrefcatID":"007","parentid":"004","prefname":"subsuborg1"}}]


OrgID   OrgName        parentID
001    org1           0 -----th top
002    org2           0
003    org3           0
004    suborg1        001
005    suborg2       001
006    suborg1       002
007    subsuborg1    004
```

like as above any number of levels need to be created

code which Im trying is able to display on screen using ul li,I need to display in dropdown list
javascript code:

```
    var menu = "<ul>";
    menu += fun_filldropdown(response, 0, menu);
    menu += "</ul>";
    $("#dropdown").html(menu);


function fun_filldropdown(response, parentid,menu)
{

    var menu = "";      
    var filtered = $.grep(response, function (el) {
        return el.Record.parentid == parentid.toString();
    });
    //alert(JSON.stringify(filtered));


    $.each(filtered, function(i, item) {


        if(item.Record.prefname !== undefined)
            {
            menu += "<li>"+item.Record.prefname+"</li>";    
            }

        if(response !== undefined)
        menu += "<ul>"+fun_filldropdown(response,item.Record.PrefcatID)+"</ul>";


    });


    return menu;

}
```

**Result Screenshot:**

[image]

can someone help me in putting in dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may refer [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ergodropdown.htm) for detail.

It works fine:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/uldropdown.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/uldropdown.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dropdown" class="uldropdown">
        </div>
        <textarea id="output" style="width: 90%;height:100px;margin-top:1em"></textarea>
        <script>
            var response=[{"Key":"001","Record":{"PrefcatID":"001","parentid":"0","prefname":"org1"}},{"Key":"002","Record":{"PrefcatID":"002","parentid":"0","prefname":"org2"}},{"Key":"003","Record":{"PrefcatID":"003","parentid":"0","prefname":"org3"}},{"Key":"004","Record":{"PrefcatID":"004","parentid":"001","prefname":"suborg1"}},{"Key":"005","Record":{"PrefcatID":"005","parentid":"001","prefname":"suborg2"}},{"Key":"006","Record":{"PrefcatID":"006","parentid":"002","prefname":"suborg1"}},{"Key":"007","Record":{"PrefcatID":"007","parentid":"004","prefname":"subsuborg1"}}];
            var menu = "<div class=\"titletext\">Select a Value</div><ul>";
            menu += fun_filldropdown(response, 0, menu);
            menu += "</ul>";
            $("#dropdown").html(menu);
            dropdown1 = new uldropdown({
                dropid: 'dropdown', // id of menu DIV container
                overlay: true, // true = drop down, false = expanding menu
                onSelect($selected){ // when user selects a value
                    $('#output').val('Selected Text: ' + $selected.text() + '\n\n' + 'Selected Value: ' + parseInt($selected.attr('key')))
                    console.log($selected.text()+","+parseInt($selected.attr("key")))
                }
            });
            function fun_filldropdown(response, parentid,menu)
            {
                var menu = "";      
                var filtered = $.grep(response, function (el) {
                    return el.Record.parentid == parentid.toString();
                });
                //alert(JSON.stringify(filtered));


                $.each(filtered, function(i, item) {


                    if(item.Record.prefname !== undefined)
                        {
                        menu += "<li><a key=\""+item.Key+"\">"+item.Record.prefname+"</a></li>";    
                        }

                    if(response !== undefined)
                    menu += "<ul>"+fun_filldropdown(response,item.Record.PrefcatID)+"</ul>";


                });
                return menu;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that url refers to only single entity dropdown not multilevel

Comment: excellent! Is it possible to get the selected id including the selected text?

Comment: any idea on why it is removing 0's, like the id is 001, but it is taking 1.

Comment: Using parseInt() function to do the job.

Comment: i tried this way  console.log($selected.text() + " id : "+ parseInt($selected.attr("key")))    showing as NaN

Comment: What browser are you using? It works on Edge, Firefox and Chrome.